# Remap cursor keys in bash vi mode to <nop> (disable cursors)

Tags: bash

When using vi mode (set -o vi) with Bash, is it possible to remap the cursor keys to  so that they don't work (and be forced to use h, j, k and l movement keys)?

Under vim (the editor), I can do it with:

```
noremap <Up> <nop>
noremap <Down> <nop>
noremap <Left> <nop>
noremap <Right> <nop>
```

But I don't know how to do it in readline's vi mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit your `.inputrc` file as follows:

```
$if mode=vi
"\eOD":""
"\e[D":""
"\eOC":""
"\e[C":""
"\eOA":""
"\e[A":""
"\eOB":""
"\e[B":""
$endif
```

It will map the arrow key to nothing.

Comment: Tested in both .inputrc and /etc/inputrc (and starting a new SSH session) and the cursors still work... Any idea? EDIT: Ok, doing "bind -f .inputrc" it's partially working. It blocks the cursors in INSERT MODE but not in COMMAND MODE. It could be enough for me, thanks! I don't know why .inputrc is not read on each login :-?

Comment: And when you call them like this: `bind '"\eOD":""'` in a running session?

Comment: No, that does not work. It only works in the .inputrc file and using the "bind -f .inputrc" command ...

Comment: @sromero I would recommend to add `set -o vi` followed by `bind -f .inputrc` into your `.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If nobody gives the full answer (block arrow keys in command mode too) I'll set your answer as the accepted one (it solved half of the problem! :).

Comment: Dear @chaos. Thanks a lot for your answer, I am marking it as the final solution.

Comment: After some tests: If you don't want to have warning messages with "scp" (bind will fail without an interactive terminal), use the following bashrc snippet instead of directly using bind:  `if [[ $- =~ i ]] &&  [[ -f ~/.inputrc ]]; then bind -f ~/.inputrc  ;  fi`